# Seeking the best method for solving simultaneous equations with very unique properties

Tags: polynomials, systems-of-equations

Hello and thank in advance for your help.  I am trying to determine the best method for solving a set of simultaneous equations with unique properties.  These equations arise from a problem in statistical quantum mechanics relating to the dynamics of quarks in theorized quark stars.  There are multiple systems of equations, and of these multiple systems, it is known that they will often have one or more solutions, but some systems may have no solutions.  The equations are unusual as described in the points below, which may suggest the development and use of special methods specific to these constraints.

Following is a summary of the nature of these equations and the system of equations:

1. The LHS of each equation is **either** a single system variable of power 1 without a coefficient such as x<sub>1</sub>, x<sub>2</sub>, or x<sub>3</sub>, **or** a positive integer.
2. The RHS of each equation is always a polynomial with terms composed of an integer coefficient (which may be one) and any unique combination of any number of the system variables.  Examples of terms would be 7x<sub>3</sub> or 9x<sub>7</sub>x<sub>9</sub>x<sub>12</sub>x<sub>23</sub>.  Following are two examples of the equations as described by (1) and (2) above:

   Example equation 1:
   v = 4v+3z+5uw-9uz+7vy+4uwx+2uvy-uvxy+12vwxy+3uvwxy
   or alternatively
   4v+3z+5uw-9uz+7vy+4uwx+2uvy-uvxy+12vwxy+3uvwxy-v=0

   Example equation 2:
   17=4u+6w-3wy+8wxy+vxy-2uvwy+7uvwxy
   or alternatively
   4u+6w-3wy+8wxy+vxy-2uvwy+7uvwxy-17=0

   In practice, I am using x with a subscript as in (2) above to represent the variables while u, v, w, x, and y were used in the examples above for visual clarity.
3. Of the two types of equations with differing LHS as described in (1)
   the type with a variable on the LHS is far more prevalent, and the type with an integer on the LHS is a small fraction of the total (and relate to initial conditions).
4. If the system can be solved, then all variable values will be equal to or greater than zero.
5. Because of the Pauli Exclusion Principle and for reasons beyond the scope of this inquiry, during symbolic algebraic substitution of variables and subsequent simplification of equations, when the same system variable is multiplied by itself any number of times in an equation to be simplified, the result is always that variable to the first power.  So for example in this unique scenario, x<sup>2</sup> or x<sup>n</sup> simplifies to x, and by extension 3u<sup>3</sup>v<sup>7</sup>z<sup>17</sup> would simplify to 3uvz.  I know that's very odd, but that's quantum mechanics for you as applied in this model. Because of (4) odd powers will never cause a sign change in a term.
6. Of the various systems of equations of this type, it is known that there may either be no solutions, one solution, or possibly multiple solutions.  In the current work, if there are multiple solutions, we only need to find one solution.
7. The system of equations is never underdetermined, but may be overdetermined.
8. As individual particle quantum states are being represented in the model, the number of variables may be large.  Depending on the resolution of the model, the number may be dozens, hundreds, or even many thousands.

I am not a mathematician, but with a mathematics background oriented toward physics and engineering, I can expand my mathematical horizons as needed to work on this problem.  I'm seeking help on getting started in the right direction with the right techniques or algorithms.  It is my hope, perhaps unrealistic, that while this system of simultaneous equations is complex due to the many variables, there may be unique and simpler approaches to its solution, given that all of the variables are to the first power and because of the unique simplification rules in point (5).

I suspect that an algorithmic approach of iterative repeated substitution and simplification might be best.  I am not not necessarily seeking the most optimal algorithm, just a workable one.  I am more than happy to write custom software for this work, which may be necessary and result in a more efficient solution than using standard methods.  Any guidance on solution methodologies would be appreciated.

I am also hoping to get guidance on the correct characterization of these equations so that I am using the correct terminology in searching for solution approaches.

Thanks again for any insights and help!

Comment: My **blind instinct**, which could easily be wrong, is that you are trying to *re-invent the wheel*.  Being totally ignorant of the science that you describe, I would be very surprised if you were the first person to ever try to attack such problems mathematically.  I suspect that in the last 100 years, mathematical approaches have evolved based on pioneering efforts of your predecessors.  I suggest finding **geezers** in your line of work, and asking their advice.  Personally, I regard re-inventing the wheel as a last resort.

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply. While I am well versed in the research related to the the underlying physics that gives rise to these equations, and other research directions are being simultaneously pursued, my current initiative in creating this post is to address only the mathematical aspect as described in the post, specifically methods for solving simultaneous equations of the unique type described.  The underlying physics was only mentioned to provide some context.  Any insights are greatly appreciated!

Comment: In your opinion, have other physicists grappled with the mathematical aspect described in your post? If so, have any of these physicists published their efforts to apply the math?  If so, would geezer physicists know of such published physics oriented math, that may have *gotten lost in the shuffle*?

Comment: @Roger Rule #5 alone is not consistent with the usual algebra, and you don't say how the other ring operations are defined. If the only rule is $x^2=x \iff x(1-x)=0$ then for example the equation $\require{cancel}x-y=0 \implies (x-y)(1-y)=0$ $\implies x(1-y)-\cancel{y(1-y)}=0$ $\implies x(1-y)=0$ $\implies x=0 \;\lor\; y=1\,$.

Comment: Thanks for your response dxiv. What you say is true  re rule #5 from the perspective of conventional multiplication, however my perhaps poorly posed question is requiring a redefinition of the multiplication operator.  I am beginning to appreciate that this extends my question into the realm of abstract algebra.  Unfortunately, my mathematical knowledge and ability does not currently extend to groups, fields, and rings, and perhaps I will need to expand my knowledge in that area to be better equipped to both pose my question properly, and to implement the desired solution.